# Correct way to typeset a long series of implied statements

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath

I have a long series of implied statements as follows:

[image]

I am using the following code to generate it in Latex (I am using AMS Math):

```
\[
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
    &&\sqrt{x^2+y^2} &= r \\
    &\implies& x^2+y^2 &= r^2 \\
    &\implies& x &= a
  \end{alignedat}
\]
```

But I don't think this is the correct way. What should be the way to typeset this?

Comment: The correct way is the one which the reader will understand.  I think your solution is perfectly acceptable.  However, please see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: @HenriMenke Edited the question.

Comment: I would not align at the equals signs

Answer (score 2):

For starters leave out the `$$` and change them for `\[`... `\]` of amsmath if you want an equation. I'd likely use `split`.

I'd also rather align them all at the left or at the equal sign as seen in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{split}
&\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = r \\
&\implies x^2+y^2 = r^2 \\
&\implies x = a\\
\end{split}
\]
\[
\begin{split}
\sqrt{x^2+y^2} &= r \\
\implies x^2+y^2 &= r^2 \\
\implies x &= a\\
\end{split}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course if you like the *extra space* I would do it this way (which is basically what you did

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
&&\sqrt{x^2+y^2} &= r \\
&\implies &x^2+y^2 &= r^2 \\
&\implies &x &= a\\
\end{aligned}
\]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While your answer definitely shows how to typeset this equation, it does not answer the question which was »What should be the way to typeset this?« as you are showing three different ways without any advice which way to go.  It's not your fault though, the questions is simply too broad.